# Only getting first row when using WHERE... IN with embedded SELECT

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7

I have a table `mission_sets` which has a field `missions`.

`mission_sets`.`missions` is a JSON array.

Here is an example value
`[1, 3, 5, 6, 8]`

There is another table `missions` who's `id` matches the arrays in `mission_set`.`missions`

I want to get the missions from `missions` based on the value of `mission_sets`.`missions`.

I have created this MySQL query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(missions,2,CHAR_LENGTH(missions)-2) FROM mission_sets WHERE `id`=7
```

which returns
    `1, 3, 5, 6, 8`

I therefore am trying to to get all the mission details using this MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM missions
WHERE `id` IN(SELECT SUBSTRING(missions,2,CHAR_LENGTH(missions)-2) FROM mission_sets WHERE `id`=7)
```

The issue is that I'm only getting the first row `1` when I run the query, not all 5 rows.

Update:
I have also tried this solution and I still ONLY GET ONE ROW BACK

```
SELECT * FROM missions
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`,(SELECT SUBSTRING(missions,2,CHAR_LENGTH(missions)-2) FROM mission_sets WHERE `id`=7))>0
```

When I replace the embedded SELECT query with the actual values, I get all the rows back.

[image: mission set table]

[image: mission table]

[image: Example Mission Set Table]

[image: Example Missions table]

Comment: Your queries don't make complete sense to me, because you are only hitting the `missions_sets` table, yet you refer to _both_ the `missions` and `id` columns, the latter of which was supposed to begin in the `missions` table.

Comment: `mission_sets` contains a field `missions` which is a JSON array of missions IDs.  I want to get that list of missions for one specific mission set, in this case mission_set 7.

Comment: I gave you an answer with a demo below, which is my interpretation of what you are asking.  If my answer be off from you expect, then you should edit your question and show the _exact_ table structure for both tables.  I dropped about 30 minutes already because you formatted your JSON data incorrectly.

Comment: When I try to use the query below, I get no rows returned.  Keep in mind I am looking for the missions of one specific mission set, in this example 7.  I have added screenshots of the table structure as well as examples.

Comment: Plesse _remove_ all the images and instead include a _minimal_ sample of data from both tables.  Then, also include the output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need JSON_TABLE, which isn't available in MySQL 5.7 and because my array is saved as integers and not strings `[1, 3, 5, 12, 14]' versus '["1", "3", "5", "12", "14"]' I am unable to use JSON_CONTAINS.  Therefore I will use the application layer to solve for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using the MySQL JSON functions here.  Join your table of IDs to the JSON array table using `JSON_SEARCH`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM missions m
INNER JOIN mission_sets ms
    ON JSON_SEARCH(ms.missions, 'all', m.id) IS NOT NULL;
```

### Demo

Comment: This does not work as my array is saved as `[1,2,3]` and JSON_SEARCH expects `["1","2","3"]`